# Let n be an integer. Prove that $n^2$ leaves a remainder of $0, 1$ or $4$ when divided by $5$.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $n$ be an integer. Prove that $n^2$ leaves a remainder of $0, 1$ or $4$ when divided by $5$.

I was asked to solve the problem stated in the title. I'd like to see if I'm correct. I'm not completely confident in what I'm doing and might've done this incorrectly.

Can someone also explain why this is correct if it is, so I can gain a full understanding of this proof?

Using the division theorem:

Case 1: $n = 5k$

$n^2 = 25k^2$

$n^2 = 5(5k^2)$

$\text{Remainder} = 0$

Case 2: $n = 5k + 1$

$n^2 = (5k + 1)^2 = 25k^2 + 10k + 1$

$n^2 = 5(5k^2 + 2k) + 1$

$\text{Remainder} = 1$

Case 3: $n = 5k + 4$

$n^2 = 25k^2 + 40k + 16$

$n^2 = 5(5k^2 + 8k + 3) + 1$

$\text{Remainder} = 1$

When $n^2$ is divided by $5$ in the cases above, the remainder are $0$ and $1$. Thus $n^2$ leaves a remainder of $0, 1,$ or $4$, when divided by $5$.

Comment: This seems an incomplete proof. But you can complete it by finishing the cases of $5k+2$, $5k+3$.

Comment: Where are $n = 5k + 2$ and $n = 5k + 3$?

Comment: @youthdoo. Thanks for the feedback. I'm slightly confused. Why do we need to finish the cases of 5k +2 and 5k+ 3 in the proof?

Comment: Because nothing in the problem mandates that $n$ *itself* must have remainder $0$, $1$ or $4$. $n$ can have *any* remainder. Including $2$ and $3$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you so much. That makes so much sense. I'll try to finish the problem now

Comment: @Dan I just realized my mistake. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: $(5n+k)^2=25n^2+10nk+k^2=k^2\text{ mod 5}$. If $k$ is one of $0,1,2,3$ or $4$, what are the possible values for $k^2\text{ mod 5}$?

Comment: Lots of people answering the question in the comment section here (I count 4 at the moment). That's hot how it's supposed to be.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks a lot. I understand the theorem a lot better now.

Comment: @Arthur While in principle I agree, many of these comments would amount to hint/partial answers that ostensibly include a question of the OP.  That's close enough to the line where answers are deleted and moved to the comments that I also understand the phenomenon.

Comment: @JohnDouma Use ```\equiv``` and ```\pmod```: $(5n+k)^2\equiv k^2 \pmod 5$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have personally never seen that happen to answers of this quality, and I also would say hints and partial answers belong squarely in the answers section. If there is follow-up, it can happen in the comments below the answer.

Comment: @BrianMoehring After all, the actual comment box below questions says "Avoid answering questions in comments", while the comment box below answers says "Use comments to ask for more information". It seems obvious to me that that's the way it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right approach: split the problem into five cases by considering numbers of the form $n = 5k + r$ for each $r \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. You just forgot to consider two of the five possible cases.

In fact, we can save a bit of work by delaying the split into different cases for as long as we can.  That is, instead of picking a specific value for $r$ and then squaring, let's square $n = 5k + r$ first:

$$\begin{aligned}
n^2 &= (5k + r)^2 \\
&= 25k^2 + 10kr + r^2
\end{aligned}$$

Now, clearly, the first two terms $25k^2$ and $10kr$ are both evenly divisible by $5$ , so the remainder from dividing $25k^2 + 10kr + r^2$ by $5$ is the same as for dividing $r^2$ by $5$.

Now we just need to check what this remainder is for each $r \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$:

$$\begin{aligned}
r = 0 &\implies r^2 = 0 \\
r = 1 &\implies r^2 = 1 \\
r = 2 &\implies r^2 = 4 \\
r = 3 &\implies r^2 = 9 = 5 + 4 \\
r = 4 &\implies r^2 = 16 = 15 + 1 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Thus, in each of these five cases, the remainder of dividing $r^2$ by $5$ is either $0$, $1$ or $4$.  And since every integer can be written as $5k + r$ for some integer $k$ and some $r \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$, this in fact holds for all integers.

Ps. As *hawaiian earring group* has noted in [their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4618028), another way of stating this result is that $0$, $1$ and $4$ are the [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $5$, and further examining this concept leads to a lot of interesting and useful results in number theory.  But I assume you'll get to those later, probably after you've become more familiar with [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) in general.

Answer (score 3):

High-falutin approach:
$$a^2=a^{\frac {5-1}2}=\pm1\pmod 5$$, which follows easily from Fermat's little theorem when $(a,5)=1.$

Replacement of $5$ by any odd prime yields an important fact from number theory, related to *quadratic residues*.

Comment: Neat proof! I guess Fermat tells us $a^4=1$, so $a^2=\pm1$ are clearly solutions; is it obvious (without a case analysis) that there are no other solutions?

Comment: Yeah,  because $a^4-1=(a^2+1)(a^2-1).$  And $\Bbb Z_5$ is of course an integral domain.   Thanks.  @DanielWagner

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I've learned a bit of Fermat's little theorem, but I'm a bit confused. Where does the 5-1/2 come from? Shouldn't it just be solely 5-1? So it should be a^4 = 1 (mod 5)

Comment: Well,  that's the part I was sort of leading you into.   It would actually be $(\dfrac a5)$, the Legendre symbol from number theory.   Don't worry too much.   You're right about Fermat's little theorem.   Note though that if you square it the $2$ goes away.

Comment: There's a lot of details.   The problem has an obvious tie-in to the subject.   That's why I mentioned it.   I'm still learning the stuff myself.

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup Thanks for the help! I'll try to review this proof along with number theory to learn more